# What happens if we stop iteration before a generator object raises a 'StopIteration' exception

Tags: python, generator

I have a `generator` object that checks a certain condition on a list. This program works fine for all my cases.

But I just want to clarify some key points.

In my program Whenever the `generator` `yield` the values `'No'` or `'Done'` the controlling iteration stops and calls the `generator` with another argument.

This may be a silly question, anyway that is, whenever the `generator` object is yielded and we stops calling next to it, does that object is settled for garbage collecting? Or is that yielded object is being settled to garbage collecting when we call that `generator` again with another argument.

Please clarify this to me what happens to a `generator` object if we stops calling `next()` on it before it raise a `StopIteration` exception. What happens to the persevered execution points and variables of the current `generator` object, when we again call the generator with a new argument.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted; it's a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debated making this a comment because I'm not an expert on the GC implementation details in Python, but decided on an answer since it seems like it might be helpful.

I think it only gets garbage collected when you lose all references to it, but it shouldn't matter, as generators are usually used to avoid storing stuff in memory, so they aren't usually very large. I think it's fine to stop using it before it hits `StopIteration`. In fact, many generators never call `StopIteration` (e.g., if they are enumerating some infinite series), so it's expected that you stop calling `next` on it before hitting the "end" in many cases.

Comment: So I hope there is no garbage collecting for this object. My doubt is what happens to the persevered execution points and variables, when we call the `generator` with a new argument

Comment: @Clarke Why shouldn't there be garbage collection? Each time you call the generator function you create a new generator object. The one you stopped iterating over gets GCed, the new one persists.

Comment: @Barmar Then the last `generator` object become an object without reference, after we create a new generator object.

Comment: @Clarke Yes, assuming you use the same varable for both of them. Another example is `list(zip(gen1(), gen2()))`. `zip()` will stop when either of the generators ends, then both of them will become garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Good question and I also used to follow this topic as I have never faced. What is found is ,
When a generator frame is (re)started(or as you said, stopping situation) as a result of a **next**() (or send() or throw()) call, one of three outcomes can occur:

- A yield point is reached, and the yielded value is returned.
- The frame is returned from; StopIteration is raised.
- An exception is raised, which bubbles out.
- In the latter two cases the frame is abandoned (and the generator object's gi_frame attribute is set to None).
  This changes to generators: when StopIteration is raised inside a generator, it is replaced with RuntimeError because of above reasons.

Please take a look for [further](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) details. thanks.